# Do Sonic's control options apply in Cyber Space?

Tags: sonic-frontiers

The game settings for Sonic Frontiers has options to change how Sonic controls. There's a notice that says "Some changes will not be reflected in some situations", but it doesn't specify which situations.

Do the changes to Sonic's physics apply in the Cyber Space time trial levels?

[image]
<sub>Screenshot from [The Nerd Stash](https://thenerdstash.com/how-do-you-change-style-of-play-in-sonic-frontiers-answered/)</sub>